# Use AND in conditional rules in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I have situation

i want to know is there away i can create and AND conditional in quicksight

currently in QS it seems on Conditional rules use OR ,
for example if one value is true than the whole thing is true

I want a situation where both values have to be true for the whole thing to be true

itried everything it seems its alimitation

Answer (score 0):

Hoi DeadUnderWater, I assume you are talking about Filters on visuals. By default, if you add multiple separate Filters to a visuals they are AND Filters (image 1). If you add a Filter condition to an **existing** Filter it is only ever an OR Filter (Image 2). So to add AND Filter conditions you simply "+ ADD" a new Filter (image 1 arrow). Hope this is what you wanted. Cheers.

[image]

[image]